# Add/include a Cmake that finds a package into CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, openblas

I found this CMake to find [OpenBLAS](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/cmake/Modules/FindOpenBLAS.cmake) but I can't find a way how to include that as an external file.

What I have in mind is like #include in C/C++. I tried googling bit i get the answer on how to include a project into CMake.

The main reason for this is that I want to have my CMake as clean and as small as possible since this is the fist time I am diving deeper in CMake world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but I can't find a way how to include that as an external file.

You need:

1. Save the module (`FindOpenBLAS.cmake`) inside your project, for example:

   ```
   Project
   └── cmake
       └── Modules
           └── FindOpenBLAS.cmake
   ```
2. Add the path into CMake variable inside `CMakeLists.txt`:

   ```
   set (CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules/")
   ```
3. Add `find_package` directive inside `CMakeLists.txt`:

   ```
   find_package (OpenBLAS REQUIRED)
   ```
4. Use populated variables, for example inside `CMakeLists.txt`:

   ```
   include_directories (${OpenBLAS_INCLUDE_DIR})
   ...
   target_link_libraries (${OpenBLAS_LIB})
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought this would be harder but I guess I was googling the wrong thing.